# How to find user in Offline to Application or Online to application using Spring MVC/Angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, spring, spring-mvc

a legend said If you can't explain it to a six-year-old, you really don't understand it yourself please make it possible now...
am looking for a idea/reference how to do this
[image]Dear Viewers/Friends, am newbie to spring mvc/angularjs. i want to develop one kind of application like registration form where name,age,phone no saving into database here when the user is in offline (if user wifi is off)it should display that you are in offline in page and if user saved his details by submitting the button it should be display items saved locally.. 
now when user in online (wifi is ON) to the application the previous entered data values in offline should be saved into database and should be display as saved succesfully in server...
we should find each time internet connection online or offline with our application.
am attaching my sample scenario image of

Comment: so you are six years old! ;) seriously you have not added the tried code. What do you want from SO? write code for you `html/css/js/spring/hibernate/....n`

Comment: i dont want the code. but i need the idea how to implement that..

Answer (score 0):

If i have to answer this question as per the question title then:

1. You can use `online` method of `navigator` object.
2. There would be a condition to check with `online/offline`.
3. Now you can use `localStorage` to set the data to the local system.
4. When user goes `offline` then save it to local.
5. Now if the system is connected to internet execute `online` method.
6. in `online` check you can use ajax to submit the data to server.
7. At serverside you have to use your logic to save the data to the specific tables.

Comment: jai thanks for giving idea but... its not upto the mark as i expected. actually am looking any reference related to this kind of example